# How to refer to a specific class or interface in android?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-lifecycle

I have the following class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

And

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {return false;}

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String searchText) {
        if (searchText.length() > 0) {
            myLiveData.removeObservers(this);
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

To the `removeObservers()` function I need to pass a `LifecycleOwner` object. When using this line:

```
myLiveData.removeObservers(this);
```

Inside my activity, it works fine but inside the `onQueryTextChange()` it fails. How to make `this` point to the right class and get the corresponding `LifecycleOwner` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not related to Android, but more related to Java and its working.

When you want to reference the outer Class inside an inner class you will use `OuterClassName.this`. In Your case it will be `MainActivity.this`

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    public void onCreate(){
        myLiveData.removeObservers(this);
    }
}
```

When working with inner class, the above code will change to this.

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    public void onCreate(){
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {return false;}

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String searchText) {
                if (searchText.length() > 0) {
                    myLiveData.removeObservers(MainActivity.this);
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```